# Register a Bower component

Tags: git, github, bower, bower-register

I try to register one of my project on Bower but it doesn't work, in first, I added my project on Github with tags and the following commands :

1. "git log"
2. "git tag 0.0.0 kj8jkh8df43..."

I used the "bower init" command to create the "manifest.json" file but when I try to register the package, I get an issue...

My issue :

```
bower Forest-Administrator#*   resolve git://github.com:tonymx227/Forest-Administrator.git#*
bower Forest-Administrator#*   ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com:tonymx227/Forest-Administrator.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port tonymx227) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

My manifest.json file :

```
{
  "name": "Forest-Administrator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tonymx227/Forest-Administrator",
  "dependencies": [
    "git://github.com/tonymx227/Forest-Administrator.git": "*"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "tonymx227 <tonymx227@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Forest Administrator is an HTML5/CSS3 framework which is used to organize your administration panel.",
  "keywords": [
    "forest",
    "administrator",
    "css3",
    "html5",
    "compass",
    "framework",
    "admin",
    "panel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests",
    ".gitignore"
  ]
}
```

Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `git://github.com/tonymx227/Forest-Administrator.git`
*Note the `/` instead of `:`*